# How to run a custom build of substrate?

Tags: substrate-node-template

I want to add logging to Substrate but use the substrate node template to test against my custom build of Substrate.  What's the easiest/fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by adding logging to Substrate?

Comment: I want to view various functions (in which modules) that are called when a tx is being processed to better understand how signed and unsigned, mortal and immortal, etc.. transactions are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone the substrate repo: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate
2. Make the changes you want to substrate.
3. Make the changes you want to the substrate node template, which is in the `substrate/bin/node-template/` folder.
4. Compile the node template with `cargo build --release -p node-template`
5. Run the node template with `./target/release/node-template --dev`

Comment: Thanks Shawn.  I didn't realize that the template was in the substrate repository because there is also a separate repository for it.

Comment: The separate repo is generated automatically from the content inside the main repo. Basically, allowing users to only get the template, versus the whole project.

Comment: Related to my question is another question:  how to enable tracing (sp_tracing) that is already in some parts of the code?

Comment: If you look at `--help` you will see the flag `-l, --log`. You can do something like `-l=trace` or `-lsync=trace` and similar. If you need more help than this, please open a new question and we can take it from there.